# How to create link to download file in ASP.NET MVC Core 2.2

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to create a link to download a file.
I have this in one page and it works, but when i move it to other page it doesn't work.

This is the link i am testing:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("GetAccessTemplateFile")" target="_blank" class="download-template">@Labels.DownloadTemplate</a>
```

In the first page that it works its inside in a form that i have copied bellow:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" asp-action="Upload">
```

The mehtod inside Controller is the following:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> GetAccessTemplateFile()
{
    string filePath = _configuration["Templates:RoomAccess"];

    string fileName = Path.GetFileName(filePath);

    byte[] fileBytes = await System.IO.File.ReadAllBytesAsync(Path.Combine(_hostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath, filePath));

    return File(fileBytes, "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet", fileName);           
}
```

This is working in page one, but if i copy the link (and method of controller) to other page it doesn't work:

- In debug mode the method in controller isn't called
- It opens a new html page equals to the other that has the link

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried putting the controller name in the @Url.Action?

Comment: @dave88, yes i have tried that and i have the same problem.